# Google Groups replies via email: link to discussion?

Tags: google-groups

When receiving replies made in a Google Groups discussion that I subscribe to, I wonder if there's a way to actually get a link to the discussion...

Right now, the only links are the following:

> You received this message because you are subscribed to a topic in the
>   Google Groups "Some Topic" group. To unsubscribe from this topic,
>   visit
>   https://groups.google.com/d/topic/some-topic-/sdhzfn-IQbs/unsubscribe?hl=en.
>   To unsubscribe from this group and all its topics, send an email to
>   some-topic-+unsubscribe@googlegroups.com. For more options, visit
>   https://groups.google.com/groups/opt_out.

Answer (score 1):

technically, the link is there - in your example it's https://groups.google.com/d/topic/some-topic-/sdhzfn-IQbs/ but it'd be nice to have a clickable one! I can't imagine why they left it out.